# Visual C++ 6.0 - fatal error C1063

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, porting, visual-c++-6

i've converted a my application originally written in MS Visual Studio 2008 to be compiled on MS Visual C++ 6.0 ([see my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925255/cvblob-compile-error-in-visual-c-6-0/)).

After the conversion of all my code now compiles in Release, without debug informations. In Debug i encounter a strange problem... the error C1063.

```
fatal error C1063: 
Error executing cl.exe. 
main.obj - 1 error(s), 163 warning(s)
```

In your opinion, what is the best practise to overcome this problem?

Comment: I think it is bad practice to dump your error codes without explanation to the SO commumnity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fatal Error C1063](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229021%28VS.60%29.aspx)

> Visual Studio 6.0
>
> compiler limit : compiler stack overflow
>
> - The program was too complex and caused
>     the compiler stack to overflow. This
>     error may be a result of recursive
>     includes.
>
> **Tips**
>
> - Simplify the program by splitting it
>     into smaller source files, and
>     recompile.

Do you have debug code that is accidently recursive?

Comment: My debug code in my opinion is not recursive (infact in MSVS2008 all works properly). 
Have you suggestion about how can I test if my debug code is recursive?
Thank you for the quick reply...

Comment: unfortunately visual c++ 6.0 raises this error with warning level 3. with warning level 0 this problem does not compare. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran in that error...

g++ would get it right since it has limits, but not as constrained as cl...

I found this page which I think is of interest in regard to this question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdscwf1c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

On my end I tried /Zm2000 to give 1Gb of space to the *compiler stack*, but that did not fix the problem. The only other way was to not have /O2 (i.e. with /Od it compiled and linked just fine.)

Actually, on first compile, the linker crashes and the on 2+ tries, cl spits out that error. I think it has to do with precompiled headers.

Just in case, since some people asked, I'm using my Controlled Variables header which is about 600Kb at this point. Just templates, but dead easy templates (really, look at them!) So I guess they use an optimization algorithm that probably checks most if not all the functions of the templates instead of just and only those necessary (which is a very small number.)

http://snapwebsites.org/project/controlled-vars